# Procession of loop variables by a scheduler in OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Loop variables are private by default. Let's assume we have for threads this loop head:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
    for(i=0; i<40; i+=2) {
    //...
    }
}
```

Before the loop starts executing, the static scheduler probably will assign the iterations as follows:

*Thread 1:* Iteration 0, 4, 8, 12, 16

*Thread 2:* Iteration 1, 5, 9, 13, 17

*Thread 3:* Iteration 2, 6, 10, 14, 18

*Thread 4:* Iteration 3, 6, 12, 15, 19

I don't understand how thread 3 knows the correct value of `i` in its third iteration (this would be the 10th iteration if the loop was executed sequentially). `i` is private,  so each thread has its own copy and increments `i`. Likewise, the value of `i` must somehow be shared. How does this work?

Comment: [Have you seen this?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5aw0hdf.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, the OpenMP compiler is going to generate a function for that loop which is going to be invoked by a number of threads in parallel.

The loop iterator is going to be normalized and bounds are going to be rewritten to be parametric on the `thread_id` and `thread_num`:

```
// code generated for #pragma omp for
void openmp_loop_0(int thread_id, int thread_num, ... closure ...) {
   for(i=thread_id; i<40/2; i+=thread_num) {
      ...a[i*2]...
   }
}

// code replaced in the main() function
thread t0(openmp_loop_0(0, 4, ...).start();
thread t1(openmp_loop_0(1, 4, ...).start();
...
openmp_loop_0(3, 4, ...)
t0.join(), t1.join(), t2.join();
```

e.g. threads are going to execute the following iterations:

```
tid #0: 0, 4, 8...
tid #1: 1, 5, 9...
tid #2: 2, 6, 10...
tid #3: 3, 7, 11...
```

That's a naive, straightforward way to implement OpenMP, it should give you an idea of how the whole machinery works.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if ´i´ is incremented randomly?

Comment: There are limitations on what you can do to your loop iterator inside the loop body. The compiler will simply tell you that that loop cannot be parallelized.

Comment: Shouldn't each thread call `openmp_loop_0` with different arguments rather than a complete other function?